# Background image is not visible in printpreview mode in telerik report viewer

Tags: asp.net, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I am using telerik reporter and I have set my background image with following code:

`this.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(emzaUrl));`

When I run the project, background image is not shown in printpreview mode but when I hit print button in reportviewer the background will appear ... I want to show background in print preview mode to allow user to decide what background should he/she use... what is the problem with print preview mode?

I had set background manually through properties window but the problem exist yet...

---

Answer:
I used water mark at last:

```
Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PictureWatermark pictureWatermark1 = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PictureWatermark();
pictureWatermark1.Image = "http://www.telerik.com/images/reporting/cars/NSXGT_7.jpg";
pictureWatermark1.Position = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.WatermarkPosition.Behind;
pictureWatermark1.PrintOnFirstPage = true;
pictureWatermark1.PrintOnLastPage = true;
pictureWatermark1.Sizing = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.WatermarkSizeMode.ScaleProportional;
pictureWatermark1.Opacity = 1;
report1.PageSettings.Watermarks.Add(pictureWatermark1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the property you are trying to set has been changed overtime and some issue may be still affecting it.

try this:

```
report.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(emzaUrl));
```

For some more reference about this problem you can find some more details [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/backgroundimage).

**Update**

I do not know your context because you have not described it. Since your problem may be caused by using a property that is not in use anymore, the answer above is to indicate that the property has been replaced by a new one with reference to the Telerik post detailing the topic.

However, you can add background images to your report in the whole report, in the header section, in the detailed section and in the footer section.
In this picture you can see that I have added the background images in all 4 cases above described.

[image]

To achieve the above I have simply used the property of each section adding the picture.
The relevant code generated in the designer.cs of the report is the following:

```
 // pageHeaderSection1
        // 
        this.pageHeaderSection1.Height = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Cm(2.5D);
        this.pageHeaderSection1.Name = "pageHeaderSection1";
        this.pageHeaderSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pageHeaderSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData")));
        this.pageHeaderSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.MimeType = "image/gif";
        this.pageHeaderSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.Repeat = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.BackgroundRepeat.NoRepeat;
        // 
        // detail
        // 
        this.detail.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("detail.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData")));
        this.detail.Style.BackgroundImage.MimeType = "image/gif";
        this.detail.Style.BackgroundImage.Repeat = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.BackgroundRepeat.NoRepeat;
        // 
        // pageFooterSection1
        //
        this.pageFooterSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pageFooterSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData")));
        this.pageFooterSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.MimeType = "image/gif";
        this.pageFooterSection1.Style.BackgroundImage.Repeat = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.BackgroundRepeat.NoRepeat;

         //Report1
        this.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Report1.Style.BackgroundImage.ImageData")));
            this.Style.BackgroundImage.MimeType = "image/gif";
```

[Here](http://youtu.be/wjfj01_RLdc) you can find a video with the result. If you still have problems, please describe accurately your context (versions, code, type of report if it is in a class library or if it is a trdx, etc..). With the information you have supplied this is the best I could answer.

Alternatively you may try to set a [watermark](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-watermarks.html) instead of the background picture.

Comment: Your code didn't change any thing... have you tried it yourself?

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I want to set the background to the whole page so I just need your last part of code. I tried it but my problem exist yet. your picture shows the applied pictures to the header,detail and footer, Can I ask you to show a picture that just set background image for whole rport in print preview mode?

Comment: @mj-y it is the one with the tiled image in the background marked //Report1. On which version are you? Is the report in a class library or in a .trdx? Are you using the Telerik report viewer or the original asp one? In the above sample I have used the Telerik report viewer and the report is in a class library.

Comment: thanks dear FeliceM, I use visual studio 2013 and Telerik_Reporting_Q1_2013_build_7.0.13.228_DEV , And I use the reporter as a class library. your code is right but I wonder why it doesn't work in my system... can I ask you to send me your demo? I will appriciate you (mj.yazdani1988@gmail.com)

Comment: I am in VS 2012 and Telerik Q2-2014, however the dll are included in the project so you should not have problem to run it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgwny9lsyf447gf/ClassLibrary_backgroundImage.rar?dl=0  and   https://www.dropbox.com/s/zazbc1qejpyskhm/TelerikWebSite6%20%282%29.rar?dl=0

Comment: thanks a lot. your dll worked well in my project, but I couldn't see the design of your class library project because of my telerik version. according to following link my problem is because of my telerik version : http://www.telerik.com/forums/report-background-image#2592796 .I couldn't find any way to solve it yet ... :(

Comment: Try using the watermark instead of the background image.http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-watermarks.html

Comment: thanks a lot dear FeliceM. I did not know that I can insert an image watermark... really thanks :-D. please insert your link in answer for others to know the solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy you find the way to solve the problem. Thanks